# content getting clipped at a certain point even after having a Horizontal Scrollbar enabled

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IBjUVy5U_q-O5beMtb7gKVmSwcsDKfad/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE6wI.png)Here, When too many items are opened at once the sidebar misbehaves. I have added a horizontal scrollbar and scrollbar is working fine I guess. But the row content gets clipped after a specific row and even scrollbar does not move after that. I have a guess here that the item width here(which are present above horizontal scrollbar) needed to be made dynamic as it would grow according to the total width of sidebar and decrease after a limit has been reached in decreasing but still should be completely present and visible completely and scrollbar should move till the end and whole content gets visible.

Stack used:
Javascript
react
html
CSS/sass

Any good Suggestions or approach for this?

Comment: give your code or link, pls

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I have added a image link in the problem statement to show what exactly problem is. Cant reveal the code as its private.

Comment: is your project local?

Comment: no. its in beta. only team members have access to it.

Comment: Does anyone know how we can fill the left space on the left for the content displayed so the content name gets visible completely in the list using CSS? probably that will fix the issue. I have not done much things in frontend and need to fix this urgently.

Comment: difficult to help when you can't see the code. if possible, give a link to the site.